# Product Detail Page getting 404 when store switch

Tags: magento2, multistore, 404-page, store-switcher

Product detail page getting 404 error when store switch. How to redirect this 404 error page to homepage or how to fix 404 error if the product exists in that store

Comment: Check the  product url attribute for each store and in the url rewrites table to see the url for each store. It must be different, you must have the same url for both stores to make it work.

Comment: yes. I have different url for each store. I want to redirect to homepage from 404 error page when I switch store